# Pass event viewer general view message as an argument in attached task

Tags: event-handling, console-application, scheduled-tasks

I already have another application that logs events and displays them. Within that application, I can include pre-defined arguments such as %message% to add said event's message as an argument.

My question is, can I do the same with event viewer tasks? the application would work basicly the same. I looked at the XML on the event view and it is encaplulated within the EVENTDATA\DATA segment.

How would I pass this entire segment as one long or multiple arguments into an application?

(currently, my app receives several arguments and just joins them together. The inner workings of the application does not matter, all I need is to pass those in as arguments to said app)

I tried some of the solutions on here such as
https://vijredblog.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/task-scheduler-event-log-trigger-include-event-data-in-mail/

This however seems to create a variable to be called and assigned to within the application, which is not what I need.

If I am wrong please feel free to correct me. If this solution would even work I would love to understand how.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.